# Should I check every single parameter of a function to make sure the function works well?

Tags: c, api, parameter-passing

I notice that the standard c library contains several string functions that don't check the input parameter(whether it's NULL), like strcmp:

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    for ( ; *s1 == *s2; s1++, s2++)
    if (*s1 == '\0')
        return 0;
    return ((*(unsigned char *)s1 < *(unsigned char *)s2) ? -1 : +1);
}
```

And many others do not do the same validation. Is this a good practice?

In other library, I saw they check every single parameter, like this:

```
int create_something(int interval, int mode, func_t cb, void *arg, int id)
{
    if (interval == 0) return err_code_1;
    if (valid(mode))   return err_code_2;
    if (cb == NULL)    return err_code_3;
    if (arg == NULL)   return err_code_4;
    if (id == 0)       return err_code_5;

    // ...
}
```

Which one is better? When you design an API, would you check all parameters to make it function well or just let it go crash?

Comment: Better to provide strong types so no checks needed. Then checking is better, but it is not free. So for performance reasons, checking is omitted in several interfaces (but then it should be in documentation).

Comment: [This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QhtXRMp3Hg) goes into great detail how to do this and why. In short you have to understand the consequences (performance, change in contract), make a decision, document it and be consistent.

Comment: As long as you document the constraints and say _undefined behavior_ otherwise, it could be a reasonable choice for performance reasons.

Comment: This is again one of those questions that really should be tagged C or C++, but not both. C simply does not have `private` functions, and in C++ there's a case to be made that a `private` function doesn't need to check its arguments (since they're called from `public` functions)

Comment: "When you design an API" : This line tells that the clients of API would be unaware of whats happening inside API and its always better to return appropriate error at every step inside of API. Reliability and Correctness matters more in API.

Comment: @MSalters C doesn't have a `private` keyword, but C certainly can have private functions by having `static` functions.  Furthermore, regarding C vs. C++, I contend that this is a philosophical question that's pretty language agnostic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to argue that not checking pointers for `NULL` in library functions that expect valid pointers is actually better practice than to do error returns or silently ignoring them.

`NULL` is not the only invalid pointer. There are billions of other pointer values that are actually incorrect, why should we give preferential treatment to just one value?

Error returns are often ignored, misunderstood or mismanaged. Forgetting to check one error return could lead to a misbehaving program. I'd like to argue that a program that silently misbehaves is worse than a program that doesn't work at all. Incorrect results can be worse than no results.

Failing early and hard eases debugging. This is the biggest reason. An end user of a program doesn't want the program to crash, but as a programmer I'm the end user of a library and I actually want it to crash. Crashing makes it evident that there's a bug I need to fix and the faster we hit the bug and the closer the crash is to the source of the bug, the faster and easier I can find it and fix it. A `NULL` pointer dereference is one of the most trivial bugs to catch, debug and fix. It's much easier than trawling through gigabytes of logs to spot one line that says "create_something had a null pointer".

With error returns, what if the caller catches that error, returns an error itself (in your example that would be `err_create_something_failed`) and its caller returns another error (`err_caller_of_create_something_failed`)? Then you have an error return 3 functions away, that might not even indicate what actually went wrong. And even if it manages to indicate what actually went wrong (by having a whole framework for error handling that records exactly where the error happened through the whole chain of callers) the only thing you can do with it is to look up the error value in some table and from that conclude that there was a `NULL` pointer in `create_something`. It's a lot of pain when instead you could just have opened a debugger and seen exactly where the assumption was violated and what exact chain of function calls lead to that problem.

In the same spirit you can use `assert` to validate other function arguments to cause early and easy to debug failures. Crash on the assert and you have the full correct call chain that leads to the problem. I just wouldn't use asserts to check pointers because it's pointless (at least on an operating system with memory management) and makes things slower while giving you the same behavior (minus the printed message).

Answer (score 2):

You can use assert.h to check your parameters:

```
assert(pointer != NULL);
```

That will make the program fail on debug mode if 'ponter == NULL', but there will be no check at all on release so you can check everything you want with no performance hit.

Anyway if a function requires parameters within a range checking that is a waste of resources, it is the user of your API who should do the checks.

But is up to you how you want to design the API. There is no correct way on that matter: if a function expects a number between 1 and 5 and the user pass a 6 you can perform a check or simply specify that the function will have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

There is no universally correct way to perform argument validation.  In general, you should use `assert` when you can to validate arguments, but `assert` is usually disabled in non-debug builds and might not always be appropriate.

There are several things to consider that can vary from case to case, such as:

- Do you expect your function to be called a *lot*?  Is performance critical?  If a caller will be invoking your function many, many times in a tight loop, then validating arguments can be expensive.  This is especially bad for inline functions and if the runtime cost of the validation checks dwarfs the runtime cost of the rest of your function.
- Are the checks easy for the caller to perform?  If the checks are non-trivial, then it's less error-prone to do validation in the function itself than forcing the extra work on the callers.  Note that in some cases, callers might not even be able to perform proper validation themselves (for example, if there's a possibility of a race condition in checking the argument's validity).
- Is your function well documented?  Does it clearly describe its preconditions, specifying what valid values for its arguments are?  If so, then you usually should consider it the caller's responsibility to pass valid arguments.
- Is your function self-documenting?  Is it obvious to callers what valid arguments are?
- Should passing a bad argument be a *logic* error or a *runtime* error?  That is, should it be considered a programmer's mistake?  Is it likely that the argument could come directly from user input?  You should consider how you expect callers to use your function.  If assertions are enabled, should a bad argument be *fatal* and terminate the program?
- Who are your function's users?  Is your function going to be used internally (where you might have some expectation for the competence of other programmers using it), or is it going to be exposed to the general public?  If the latter, what failure mode will minimize the amount of technical support that you need to provide? (The stance I took with my [dropt library](http://www.taenarum.com/software/dropt/) is that I relied on assertions to validate arguments to internal functions and reported error codes for public functions.)

Answer (score 0):

> I notice that the standard c library contains several string functions that don't check the input parameter(whether it's NULL), like strcmp:

The string handle functions of the standard C library require "... pointer arguments on such a call shall still have valid values ..." C11dr §7.24.1 2

`NULL` is not a valid pointer to a string and there is no requirement on the function's part to check pointer validity, so no `NULL` check.
C's performance does come at a price.

> When you design an API, would you check all parameters to make it function well or just let it go crash?

This enters design philosophy.  Consider a simpler example.  Should the API test the input parameters first? It depends on coding goals.

```
int add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

// return 1 on failure
int add_safe(int *sum, int a, int b) {
  if (a >= 0) { 
    if (b > INT_MAX - a) return 1; // Overflow
  } else { 
    if (b < INT_MIN - a) return 1; // Underflow
  } if (sum) { // NULL check
    *sum = a + b;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When in doubt, create an API that does **nominal** checking.  Use **strong checking**  of inputs that may originate from a user (human) or another process.  If you want heavy pedantic checking, C is not an efficient target language choice.

With many an API I have made, `NULL` is a valid input value as a pointer and code adjusts its functionality base on that as above.   A `NULL` check is made, but it is not an *error* check.

Comment: Your example is insightful, thanks. In the end,  you say `NULL` is valid input and `NULL` check is not error check, what does this suppose to mean, sorry, but I didn't get it.

Comment: @elinx With `strcmp()`, `NULL` is not a valid input like `float x; strcmp(&x, ...)` is not a valid input.  Code should not expect `NULL` nor `&x` is validated as part of the `strcmp()` call.  With many functions I create, `NULL` is a valid input.  so a check against `NULL` is expected.  It is not because `NULL` is an error, it is because `NULL` indicates a different functionality.